# TaskCompletionSource throwing error but not sure why

Tags: c#, webclient

```
    public static Task<string> GetData(string url, string data)
    {
        UriBuilder fullUri = new UriBuilder(url);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            fullUri.Query = data;

        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Error != null)
                tcs.TrySetException(args.Error); // HERE
            else if (args.Cancelled)
                tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            else
                tcs.TrySetResult(args.Result);
        };

        client.DownloadStringAsync(fullUri.Uri);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

The above method is getting to the error at "//Here"...

[image]

the thing is, I believe the URL and parameters to be correct. Any typical things I should check out first apart from creating my own API page for it to go to?

Comment: It says right there in `InnerException`: "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."  So there you go, it's a straightforward 404.

Comment: Damn, I really can't understand why it is 404, I've copied the code straight off of the api that I know works. Hm, I'll try again with a test url.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you could just use [`WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194294.aspx) instead of wrapping your own method.

That being said, the exception is simply the exception returned from `WebClient`.  The `InnerException` is very explicit - The server returned NotFound (ie: a 404 error code).  Your code which sets the exception appears perfectly valid.